# Is it possible to change height of iFrame from child document when you have don't have access to the parent document?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dom-events, iframe-resizer

I'm trying to add a child document into an iFrame in parent document. I don't have access to the parent page and it always shows iframe height 0. Is it possible to change this height from the child document?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span>This is parent document that I don't have access to.</span>
        <iframe src="src_to_my_page" style="border: none; height: 0px;">
            // document that I have access to.
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The height of this iframe is always 0 no matter what the document is and since I have no access to the parent document, is there a way to change it?

Comment: Please provide [minimal code to reproduce output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/McLaren) in your question!

Comment: @Kshitiz added code

Comment: @David already answered, aren't you satisfied with that answer? I think that is clear and convincing.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to change the height of an iFrame from the parent page. If you don’t have access, then your out of luck and we need to talk to the developers of the parent site